# span returns to the line when i add a margin-left in %

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to add `margin-left` to the span in percentage, But the result is not as I want. It works only if I change the property display added to the label by bootstrap to block,
Can anyone explain this behavior to me, and offer a solution?
Thanks in advance.

```css
label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.field-description {
    margin-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<label class="gender-item">
  <input type="radio" id="male" class="field-checkbox" name="gender" value="">
  <span class="field-description">male</span>
</label>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image of what's happening and what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Did you try giving `padding-left`?

Comment: The problem persists

Comment: Can't help you until you show a "replicatable" problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Percentage values relative to an inline-block that does not have an explicitly defined dimenion may cause weird problems, either refrain from using the percentage unit, or you could force the content to remain in one line with `white-space: nowrap`;

```css
label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.field-description {
    margin-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<label class="gender-item">
  <input type="radio" id="male" class="field-checkbox" name="gender" value="">
  <span class="field-description">male</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Guess you want span to be inline
`Check here`[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/sagarpednekar04/3947re4a/#&togetherjs=NLDboRSzNq)